FRM-47100 : Cannot read image
When I am storing photos in Oracle 10g using oracle forms 6i some JPG images are getting saved but some JPG images are not getting saved.
Give an error like FRM-47100 :cannot read image file
DECLARE
    str    VARCHAR2(256);
BEGIN
    -- Prompt the user to select an image file of any type
    str := GET_FILE_NAME(FILE_FILTER => 'Image Files (*.bmp;*.gif;*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png)|*.bmp;*.gif;*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png|All Files (*.*)|*.*|');
    
    -- Check if a file was selected
    IF str IS NOT NULL THEN
        -- Read and display the selected image
        READ_IMAGE_FILE(str, 'AUTO', 'photo1'); -- 'AUTO' format will attempt to determine the image format automatically
    ELSE
        -- Display a message if no file was selected
        MESSAGE('No file selected.');
    END IF;
END;

I want to store all jpg format in my database.

If you compare JPG files' size, how large are files you can not load (compared to size of files you can load)?
